# How to write a django-like Class ("Models") initialization

Tags: python, django

I have an object called a "TemporaryPriceReduction" that tells me information on a product that undergoes a sale. The class looks something like this:

```
class TPR:
    def __init__(self, product_id, territory):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.territory = territory
```

In django models, it allows you to define things outside an init (at least in the specific model that inherits the `models.Model` base class:

```
class TPR(models.Model):
    product_id = ...
    territory = ...
```

Basically, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
class TPR(AbstractClass):
    product_id = product_id
    territory = territory
```

How could I build something like an abstract base class so that I can define things outside the `init` (like in django) rather than having to write the init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a feature of plain python, not specifically django.

When you assign `self.product_id = ...` in `__init__`, you are assigning an attribute in the instance called `product_id`.

When you assign `product_id = ...` in the class body, you are creating an attribute in the class, `TPR.product_id`. Instances of your class will not have such an attribute unless you explicitly assign them. Python attribute lookup works such that `instance.product_id` will find missing attributes in the class. That implies that all instances that do not explicitly override `product_id`, e.g. in `__init__`, share the same object as their `product_id` through the class.

The point is that you can define attributes using the syntax you want without doing anything special at all with base classes.

Comment: I see -- so then what's the advantage/disadvantages of putting the variables within the instance `__init__` rather than just putting it at the class level? Also, I think you forgot to complete the second sentence in the second paragraph.

Comment: @David542 Thanks for the catch. I have already described the advantages/disadvantages by explaining the differences in behavior. What you consider an advantage depends entirely on what you are trying to do.